# Is using NoIP with hMail or Mercury mail possible?

Tags: email, hmail-server, noip

I have **DDNS with no IP** address (free) and its IP / target is **127.0.0.1** (localhost). Is it possible to use this domain as an E-mail server in the program such as Mercury or hMail? If so, how?